# How do I make div element responsive?

Tags: html, css

I am having a SVG file over which I have two div tags for each shape
in my SVG file. small box when clicked opens a new page and big box
when clicked opens another page for this i use  now when I re-size
my browser my div moves away and is not responsive but using
illustrator i made my SVG file responsive, How do I make my div
elements responsive when re-sized? Can some one help me code?
Here is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <style>
    .gold1 {
      position: absolute;
      top: 9px;
      left: 10px;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    #small {
      height: 98px;
      width: 92px;
      float: left;
      position: absolute;
      right: 500px;
      top: 271px;
      left: 222px;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    #big {
      height: 168px;
      width: 140px;
      float: left;
      position: absolute;
      right: 700px;
      top: 271px;
      left: 397px;
      z-index: 1;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1024 768" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1024 768;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
      .st0 {
        fill: #8C6239;
        stroke: #000000;
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
      }
      .st1 {
        fill: #908FB2;
        stroke: #000000;
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
      }
      .st2 {
        fill: #D3D2E0;
        stroke: #000000;
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
      }
      .st3 {
        font-family: 'MyriadPro-Regular';
      }
      .st4 {
        font-size: 12px;
      }
    </style>
    <rect id="XMLID_1_" x="128.5" y="164.6" class="st0" width="808.5" height="492.7" />
    <path id="XMLID_2_" class="st1" d="M215.1,273.1h-37.8c-12.1,0-22-9.8-22-22v-31.7c0-12.1,9.8-22,22-22h37.8c12.1,0,22,9.8,22,22
 v31.7C237,263.3,227.2,273.1,215.1,273.1z" />
    <path id="XMLID_3_" class="st2" d="M381.6,336.5h-68.3c-11.8,0-21.3-9.6-21.3-21.3v-96.3c0-11.8,9.6-21.3,21.3-21.3h68.3
 c11.8,0,21.3,9.6,21.3,21.3v96.3C402.9,327,393.3,336.5,381.6,336.5z" />
    <text id="XMLID_4_" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 185.8291 225.561)" class="st3 st4">A</text>
    <text id="XMLID_5_" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 313.8779 242.6343)" class="st3 st4">B</text>
  </svg>

  <a href="small.html">
    <div id="small">
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="big.html">
    <div id="big">
    </div>
  </a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: when I run the code snippet in full screen $ resize - it is responsive... what is the problem?

Comment: no my div element is not responsive they hold a reference to different page when I re-size my browser my reference over image is moved away. how to move along with SVG size

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused on whether you mean to make it's size responsive, or it's position responsive. So I'll answer both.

If you want to make the size responsive then you need to replace the "width: 140px;" with whatever percent of it's parent element you want it to take up. I.E. "width:20%;"

It's pretty similar with positioning, just a couple of words are changed. Instead of "left:222px;" you would make it a percent that you want it to move. I.E "left: 20%;" The only note with this is that the percentages are based off of the top left corner of the element rather than the middle. So if you plan on centering an element in the future check [this out](https://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/)

Comment: I need to make the position responsive and SVG file is already responsive. I need to make that div element responsive

Comment: responsive can mean two things, have it's size change when the screen size changes, or have it stay in a certain position when the screen changes. I don't know much about SVG, but the question you're asking seems to be a simple css question so I jumped in.

Comment: no my size should change according to browser size. for example I have a div element with 90px x 90px then when my browser is re-sized smaller my div size must be adjusted accordingly

Comment: a px or pixel is not relative, 1 pixel, will always be one pixel. So you need to use relative sizes to figure out how this works, I suggest trying a couple of percent values and seeing which one fits your screen best. I don't understand SVG's, so if they have some special characteristic that automatically makes everything inside of it relative,  then you're asking the wrong person.

Comment: This is where css gets confusing, a px is an exact measurement, like an inch or a foot, no matter where you put it, it doesn't change in size. I don't know the size of your computer, but I'm thinking you want it to be relative to a certain size. Screw around with percents(you can go into decimals), and find one that matches 90px on your computer.

Comment: thats what I am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are looking for this.. stills your question should be more specific

**Html**

```
<div id="small">Small</div>
<div id="big">Big</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
div {
    max-width:100%;
    border:1px solid #dddddd;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
}
#small {
    width:30%;
    min-height:30%;
    background:yellow;
}
#big {
    width:60%;
    min-height:60%;
    background:greenyellow;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oao7xgfh/)

Comment: how do I position my div in desired position?

Comment: when I give top value responsive does not work? should top values must be in percentage?

Comment: why height is made auto?

Comment: sorry my mistake, there is no need to set height auto

Comment: then what should I do?

Comment: whats is ur problem now, if you need to set top value, set the value in percentage and see the output

Comment: no problem with that. when I make size so small it moves ahead Cant it be made accurate?

Comment: i made it too small and didnt get any misalignment with this, can you check n confirm this updated link http://jsfiddle.net/oao7xgfh/2/

Comment: there is still misalignment when I make it with my SVG file